# Haskell - Types, Enums, and Functions

Tags: function, haskell, types, enums

Good morning everyone,

Here's what I'm working on today, and the issue I'm running in to:

```
--A
data Row = A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J deriving (Enum, Ord, Show, Bounded, Eq, Read)
data Column = One | Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven | Eight | Nine | Ten  deriving (Enum, Ord, Show, Bounded, Eq, Read)
--B
data Address = Address Row Column deriving (Show, Read, Eq)
```

Then a few lines later I get to the problem child:

```
toAddress r c = Address(toEnum r, toEnum c)
```

I need to feed Address a Row and Column, but I need to turn r and c into Row and Column (not Ints)

Obviously toAddress is not structured correctly to carry out this task. The requirement is as follows:

> Write a function toAddress that takes in a row and column, each in [0
>   − 9]. Construct an Address and return it. Use toEnum to index into
>   your Row and Column enums lists.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to accomplish what I'm going for here?

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks to whoever downvoted this already.

Comment: Have you tried `Address (toEnum r) (toEnum c)`?

Comment: The first thing that looks suspicious with your solution is `Address(toEnum r, toEnum c)`. `Address` here is a constructor, which is just like a function. But the syntax you are using is nothing like the syntax for function application in Haskell.

Comment: So you folks would recommend something like this: `toAddress r c = Address(toEnum r) (toEnum c)`

Comment: Spaces make it a little more readable. And it's not just a recommendation. It's the way Haskell works. Forget everything you know about imperative languages (C, C++, Java, whatever you used before).

Comment: Are you referring to the space (lacking) between Address and (toEnum r)?

Comment: Yes, that space. In a way, `Address` is a function too.

Comment: Alright, that's good to know. So, does the line I copied here look good now? `toAddress r c = Address (toEnum r) (toEnum c)`

Comment: @Lii and Rhymoid if either of you wants to post one of your comments as an answer I'll be glad to accept it, both of you greatly helped solve my problem and I'm now successfully compiling wherein it wasn't before. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got the syntax wrong.

A function application of a function `f :: A -> B -> C` in haskell looks like this `f a b` and not `f(a,b)`. `f(a,b)` still is correct syntax but not what you want: it passes only one parameter to the function (i.e. the tuple consisting of a and b).

So the correct implementation of `toAddress` looks like this:

```
toAddress r c = Address (toEnum r) (toEnum c)
```

Comment: Thank you sir, your help is greatly appreciated! Haskell is new to me, I've done largely imperative programming up until now. New mindset, but I really like it.